# How to transfer Core Data store from provisioned iPhone to iPhone simulator?

Tags: iphone, xcode, core-data

I have a lot of data stored in my app on my provisioned device, and I want to do additional testing on my computer which is much faster than using the device. What is the best way to transfer the data store into the iPhone simulator so I can access it on the computer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think that you can download the data from your device in the Organizer in Xcode.

Once you unzip that folder you should be able to find your sqlite database file.

Now look for the folder on your hard drive where the simulator keeps its files. I think it's somewhere in ~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator or something like that. There should be a folder for each app somewhere in there (the folder name will be some random ID), and you should be able to find an sqlite database with the same name. Replace that database with the one you downloaded from the device.

Sorry I can't give more detailed instructions. I'm at work currently and don't have access to my Macbook to get the exact folder names and such.

Comment: This is correct.  Once you go digging around under the iPhone Simulator directory you should see the structure easily enough.

Comment: Thanks - this worked correctly! You don't actually have to unzip any files. The sqlite database is in the Documents folder.